# Construct a 16-to-1 line multiplexer with two 8-to-1 line multiplexers and one 2-to-1 line multiplexer?

Tags: logic, digital

please help me regarding above question.any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this was anything to do with programming... http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Construct_a_16-to-1-line_multiplexer_with_two_8-to-1-line_multiplexers_and_one_2-t0-1-line_multiplexer

Comment: yes..infact this question is father of programming.

Comment: one who does'nt study computer architecture and digital logic design i dont think he is a programmer :)

Comment: @user1893486: see this link : [**`electronics.stackexchange`....**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), aks this question there.

Answer (score 1):

Say the select lines are S3 S2 S1 S0 , use txo 8x1 mux and use S2 S1 S0 as select lines for both of them , now connect the output of two mux to another 2x1 mux with upper 8x1 mux output as 1st input and next one as second input , now use remaining select line (S3) as select line for 2x1 mux , take the output from it..